# distance between sets in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I was given this innocent looking homework question.

> Given two nonempty sets $A,B \subseteq X$ where $(X,d)$ is a metric space.
>
> 1. Show that $\mathrm{dist}(A,B) = \inf \{d(x,y) \mid x \in A, y \in B \}$ is well-defined.
> 2. Suppose $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Suppose $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact. Show that $\mathrm{dist}(A, B) > 0$.

Aren't both (1) and (2) properties of the fact that $S = \{ d(x,y) \mid x \in A, y \in B \}$ is a subset of $P = \{ x \mid x \ge 0 \}$, which is bounded?

for (1): $S \subseteq P$ and $P$ bounded implies $S$ is bounded. Hence $\mathrm{inf} S$ exists. Since $\mathrm{inf} S$ is unique, we conclude that $\mathrm{dist}(A, B)$ is well defined.

for (2): Since $\mathrm{inf} P \ge 0$ and $S \subseteq P$, $\mathrm{dist}(A, B) \ge 0$. Since $A \cap B = \emptyset$, $x \ne y$ $\forall x \in A, y \in B$. Then $d(x,y) \ne 0$. Hence $\mathrm{dist}(A,B) > 0$.

Am I missing something very very obvious? Where does compactness come into play?

Comment: I suspect in (1), you want $\mathrm{dist}(A,B)$ on the LHS.

Comment: yup. thanks for pointing that out. fixed.

Comment: The proof for (2) isn't correct. Individual dist. are > 0, but the inf may still be 0. This is why you need compactness of B.

Comment: (2) You can have two sequences of points with distances between 0 and $1/n$. Use the compactness (and the Force).

Comment: Hint for (2):  What can you say about $X \setminus \left( A \cup B \right)$?  (This is a "picture" hint that may suggest a way to proceed.)

Comment: In what sense should dist be *well-defined*, instead of simply *defined*? The right hand side does not depend on any choice.

Comment: $dist$ is a function. By definition, to show that a function $f: D \to E$ is well-defined, one has to show that (1) $f(D)$ exists and (2) for every $x \in D$, $f(x) = a$ and $f(x) = b$ implies $a = b$.

Comment: The reason your argument for (2) is not valid is that you have not used the compactness or closedness of $A, B.$  For example if $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, with $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[-1,0)$ then $A$ is compact but $B$ is not closed and dist($A,B)=0.$

Comment: @EricTowers I can say that $X \setminus (A \cup B)$ is open, but I don't see where this goes ? (I can follow the sequential compactness argument, just curious what you have in mind).

Comment: @TomCollinge : It's been a few years, so this reconstruction may be not be 100% what I was thinking.  $X \smallsetminus (A \cup B)$ is open, so any point on a metric geodesic between $A$ and $B$ has an open neighborhood of positive diameter.  You need compactness to avoid, e.g., $A$ and $B$ being the components of the graph of $y \leq \ln|x|$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 1, $S$ might be unbounded, contrary to your statement. But you have exactly the right idea: it is bounded *below* by 0, and that is all you need.

$\def\dist{\operatorname{dist}}$But for 2 your idea is no good.  Let $A = (-1,0)$ and $B = (0, 1)$.  Then $A\cap B = \phi$, and yet $\dist(A, B) = 0$.  There are no two points $a\in A, b\in B$ with distance zero, as you said, but there *are* points $a,b$ at arbitrarily small distance, and that is all we need for the infimum of $S$ to be zero.   So if we want to prove that $\dist(A,B)>0$, it is not enough to know that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint; we need some additional information about $A$ and $B$. That is where the compactness comes in.

In fact it's not even enough for the two sets to be closed; the usual example is that the hyperbola $H = \{ \langle x,y\rangle \mid xy = 1 \}$ is closed and the $x$-axis $L = \{ \langle x,y\rangle \mid y = 0 \}$ is closed, but $\dist(H, L) = 0$ because for any positive $s$ we can choose $0<t<s$ and then $h = \left\langle \frac1t, t\right\rangle, \ell = \left\langle \frac1t, 0\right\rangle$ are closer than $s$.

Comment: hm. good point. I see where the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Comment: The important point for 1 is that $S\ne\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

You should show that $d_S(x):=\operatorname{inf}_{s\in S}d(s,x)$ is a continous function (for all subsets $S$). If you have that, then
$$
d(A,B)=\operatorname{inf}_{x\in B}d_A(x)=\operatorname{inf}_{x\in A}d_B(x)
$$
Now if $B$ is compact $d_A$ has a Minimum $m$ on $B$, say at the point $b\in B$. By definition, we find a sequence $a_n \in A$ such that $d(a_n,b)\rightarrow m$. If $m=0$, this would imply that $a_n \rightarrow b$. But $A$ is closed, so $b\in A$ is impossible $\Rightarrow m>0$