# Compactness and Distance?

Tags: analysis, compactness, bounded-variation

Let $K$ and $L$ be nonempty compact sets, and define

$$d = \inf\{ |x-y| : x \in K \textrm{ and } y\in L \}$$

This turns out to be a reasonable definition for the distance between $K$ and $L$.

1. If $K$ and $L$ are disjoint, show $d > 0$ and that $d = | x_{0}-y_{0}|$ for some $x_{0}\in K$ and $y_{0}\in L$;
2. Show that it's possible to have $d = 0$ if we assume only that the disjoint sets $K$ and $L$ are closed.

My teacher explained to me that I could say something along the lines of:
If we find a sequence in the set $K$, $(x_n)$, and a sequence in the set $L$, $(y_n)$ and we assume that they have the same limit then they are approaching the same number. But since $K$ and $L$ are compact, then they are closed which means they contain their limit points and $K$ and $L$ must contain the limit of the sequences. I am not really sure where to go from there or how to write that in a formal proof. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe this helps> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652932/distance-between-sets-in-a-metric-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are sequences $(x_n)$ in $K$ and $(y_n)$ in $L$ such that

$$d=\lim_{n \to \infty}|x_n-y_n|.$$

Since $K$ is compact, there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ with $x_{n_k} \to x_0 \in K$ ($k \to \infty$)

Since $L$ is compact, $(y_{n_k})$ contains a convergent subsequence  $(y_{n_{k_j}})$ such that $y_{n_{k_j}} \to y_0 \in L$ ($j \to \infty$).

Then we have:
$$ d=\lim_{j \to \infty}|x_{n_{k_j}}-y_{n_{k_j}}|=|x_0-y_0|.$$